# D3 color hex from json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to fill my node in `3D.js` with `hexdecimal` color from the `json`. So here the example of `json` file.

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"GCF_000008865.1",
"choose":"1",
"organism_name":"Escherichia coli O157:H7 str. Sakai",
"classification":"cellular organisms; Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Gammaproteobacteria; Enterobacterales; Enterobacteriaceae; Escherichia; Escherichia coli; Escherichia coli O157:H7;",
"lineage":"bacteria>proteobacteria>gammaproteobacteria",
"genera":"Escherichia",
"colorsamp":"#E7298A",
"id":"GCF_000008865.1"},
{"name":"GCF_000006945.2",
"choose":"1",
"organism_name":"Salmonella enterica subsp. enterica serovar Typhimurium str. LT2","classification":"cellular organisms; Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Gammaproteobacteria; Enterobacterales; Enterobacteriaceae; Salmonella; Salmonella enterica; Salmonella enterica subsp. enterica; Salmonella enterica subsp. enterica serovar Typhimurium;",
"lineage":"bacteria>proteobacteria>gammaproteobacteria",
"genera":"Salmonella",
"colorsamp":"#CCEBC5",
"id":"GCF_000006945.2"},
```

The `colorsamp` field has the hexadecimal color code, so I'm trying to fill this way:

```
// draw circles for each node
    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        // circle
        .enter().append("circle")
        // radius of the circle
        .attr("r", (d) => {
            if (d.choose == 0 ) {return 5;}
            if (d.choose == 1) {return 8;}
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { d.colorsamp; })
              .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
        // add text of mouse over, show name and value (% or raw?)
        node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return (d.name+ "\n" + d.lineage + " (" + d.genera +")"); });
```

Everything seams work fine unless the `fill` function which don't fill the nodes with colors.

Obs: I'm usin `D3.js v4` because `v5` are not working with my code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the `colorsamp` in the fill function.

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { d.colorsamp; })
```

Should be

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return d.colorsamp; })
```

Or

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return d.colorsamp; })
```

If you don't want clashing with CSS.

```js
const pinkHex = '#E7298A';

const colors = ['#E7298A', 'orange', 'green'];

d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(colors)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', (d, i) => (i * 50) + 25)
  .attr('cy', (d, i) => (i * 30) + 25)
  .attr('r', 5)
  .attr('fill', (d) => d)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's still not working. Are some possibility of to be the `hex` color code.

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes I added a snippet. The first color is one of the hex from your data. Might you have some css which is causing an issue? You could change `.attr('fill', ...` to `.style('fill'...`

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes If this answered your question if you could mark as answered that would be great!

Comment: sorry, I didn't finished to debug. I was testing. I have none css messing up the layout. But was solved. Thanks